# node.js] how to catch GET in server.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to run function in server, then use `$.ajax` in `website.js`
First, i want to test ajax and cathc GET in server.
I'll try to test the function that displays "hellooooo" on the console by simply catching GET.
 However, the code is not working properly.

this is code in `server js`

```
##  server.js  ##

const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const path = require('path');
const EventHubReader = require('./scripts/event-hub-reader.js');
const SendMessage = require('./public/js/C2D.js');

const iotHubConnectionString = process.env.IotHubConnectionString;
if (!iotHubConnectionString) {
    console.error(`Environment variable IotHubConnectionString must be specified.`);
    return;
}
console.log(`Using IoT Hub connection string [${iotHubConnectionString}]`);

const eventHubConsumerGroup = process.env.EventHubConsumerGroup;
console.log(eventHubConsumerGroup);
if (!eventHubConsumerGroup) {
    console.error(`Environment variable EventHubConsumerGroup must be specified.`);
    return;
}
console.log(`Using event hub consumer group [${eventHubConsumerGroup}]`);

// Redirect requests to the public subdirectory to the root
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res /* , next */) => {
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('./send/', function(req,res) {
    console.log("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.broadcast = (data) => {
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            try {
                console.log(`Broadcasting data ${data}`);
                client.send(data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
    });
};

server.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000', () => {
    console.log('Listening on %d.', server.address().port);
});

    const eventHubReader = new EventHubReader(iotHubConnectionString, eventHubConsumerGroup);

(async () => {
    await eventHubReader.startReadMessage((message, date, deviceId) => {
        try {
            const payload = {
                IotData: message,
                MessageDate: date || Date.now().toISOString(),
                DeviceId: deviceId,
            };

            wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify(payload));
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error broadcasting: [%s] from [%s].', err, message);
        }
    });
})().catch();
```

i can found GET log in my application console

```
console message 

2020-05-15 08:43:23 test GET /send/
```

but i can't find result of this code

```
app.get('./send/', function(req,res) {
    console.log("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
});
```

what is problem in my code, and how can i modify to run correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is supposed to be a '.' dot in `./send/`. Maybe it should just be `/send`